# Handling complex types of wsdl using php in server side

Tags: php, wsdl

I am using php to write the service in server side. following is my wsdl request and response types

```
  <xsd:element name="testServiceRequest">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="identifier" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="params" type="abc:Parameters"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="testServiceResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="response" type="abc:responseType"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>


  <xsd:complexType name="Parameter">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="key" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="Parameters">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="param" type="abc:Parameter" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="responseType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="resultCode" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="resultDesc" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

Can somebody please help me how to write the php function to get the parameter values and how to write the return of that copmlex type.

My php function looks like

```
function testService($params) {
    // how can I get the parameter values ????
  return "";
   // what should I return to compatible with return type ???

}
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Although not the answer you're looking for. I think you may have switched Parameter and Parameters in your wsdl. I'm assuming you wanted the plural Parameter for multiple parameters and the singular for a single parameter. Currently you have that reversed.